# How to show user list of .apk files programmatically from sd card?

Tags: java, android

The following code should enumerates list of apk files but for some reason it does not. I am trying to get the list of .apk files programmatically sop that I can choose one .apk file from that list which I can select to install. Is it possible?

```
public class InstallAPKActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ExtFilter apkFilter = new ExtFilter("apk");
    File file[] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles(apkFilter);
    Log.d("InstallApk", "Filter applied. Size: "+ file.length);

    for (int i=0; i < file.length; i++)
    {
        Log.d("InstallApk", "FileName:" + file[i].getName());
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file[i]),   
"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

class ExtFilter implements FilenameFilter { 
    String ext; 
    public ExtFilter(String ext) { 
        this.ext = "." + ext; 
    } 
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) { 
        return name.endsWith(ext); 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I used this code and it works fine.

Comment: @Manikandan: hey its give me an error like: ERROR Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.a.android.GetapkActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.a.android-1.apk]

Answer (score 1):

Well, you must do the searching recursively. What you are doing is listing the files in the parent directory only.

[This Page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) explains how to walk the file tree.

You can also do Google Searches, but I find Oracle's official pages to be more useful.

I found [This Page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html) to be more useful. This page talks about `PathMatcher` which is not available for Android.

Only place where it uses the `PathMatcher` class is:

```
 void find(Path file) {
            Path name = file.getFileName();
            if (name != null && matcher.matches(name)) {
                numMatches++;
                System.out.println(file);
            }
        }
```

in which case you can replace `matcher.mathces(name)` with `file.getName().endsWith(".apk")` and then modify the code however you please.

Comment: Unfortunately this requires the import of java.nio.(*), which doesn't seem to be apart of Android.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code to see the list of apk files. I am able to get the list of apk files

**The following code shows list of apk files present in your SDCard**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyListView extends Activity {




   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ExtFilter apkFilter = new ExtFilter("apk");
        File file[] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles(apkFilter);

        Log.i("InstallApk","Filter applied. Size: "+ file.length);

        for (int i=0; i < file.length; i++)
        {
            Log.i("InstallApk", "FileName:" + file[i].getName());

        }



   }



    class ExtFilter implements FilenameFilter { 
        String ext; 
        public ExtFilter(String ext) { 
            this.ext = "." + ext; 
        } 
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) { 
            return name.endsWith(ext); 
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: That only lists files on the parent directory. That is - it only lists files on /mnt/sdcard/ but not files within /mnt/sdcard/downloads/ or /mnt/sdcard/otherDirectories/